# Modify name of item in cart

Tags: php, magento-1.7, magento

I'm trying to append string `ABC` to the name of each item added to the cart. This should be show in cart/checkout and be accessible programmatically.

So far, I have overloaded `Mage_Checkout_CartController` with my custom `ABC_DEF_CartController` as such:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <ABC_DEF before='Mage_Checkout'>ABC_DEF</ABC_DEF>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

New `CartController.php` overloades `addAction()`:

```
public function addAction(){
    //prepare 
    $cart = $this->_getCart();
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $params['qty']=1;


    try{
        $product = $this->_initProduct();
        $product->setData('qty',1);

        if(!$product){
            //TODO product not found
            return;
        }

        $product->setData('name',$product->getName()."ABC");
        $cart->addProduct($product,$params);
        $cart->save();

        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
            );   
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //TODO
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
```

---

By my understanding, all the basic product information are re-loaded from database somewhere but I cannot figure where or how to make changes persistent. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you better hook onto the event `sales_quote_item_set_product`. This event is dispatched in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::setProduct()`.
Prior to dispatching the event there is this line:

```
->setName($product->getName())
```

so I assume that you can change the name in a custom observer for the event I mentioned.
The event receives as parameters the current quote item and the product assigned to it.